# JSQMessagesViewController crashes with 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am using JSQMessages installed through Cocoapods.

I started getting this crashes:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/XXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E4479289-9068-420E-8D2E-C147129BD60E/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/81C1166D-426F-4C68-B3FB-89164E2C35DC/XXXXXXXXXX.app> (loaded)' with name 'JSQMessagesViewController''

*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011304434b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000112aa521e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001130ad265 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x000000011143901a -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 507
    4   XXXXXXXXXXXX                        0x000000010e2fb3bf -[JSQMessagesViewController viewDidLoad] + 143
```

Which crashes in this method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[[self class] nib] instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

    [self jsq_configureMessagesViewController];
    [self jsq_registerForNotifications:YES];
}
```

I have searched and tried every single solution of the many ones proposed in StackOverflow and in other sites, and I have spent two days on it with no success.

Please help me point in the right direction. 
Thanks!!

Comment: Search whether you have the `JSQMessagesViewController.xib` exists in the give path. I don't think so it is there. Also, check in the pods project whether the `JSQMessagesViewController.xib` is added or not.

Comment: @New16 Thanks, forgive my ignorance but,  
Where do I add it? in Pod Target Build Phases? Which section?

Comment: @New16 You are right, that Device folder doesnt exist in /Users/XXXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ !!  Why is that? How can I solve it?

Comment: Run pod install again. Are you using the older versions of `JSQMessages`.

Comment: I already had run pod install and pod update, last versions installed. I also uninstalled JSQMessages and reinstall it again, cleaned project, restart, add bundle to build phases, and many other things...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY solved it by:

1. Add a new "Copy Bundle resources" phase in the build phases for the pod target.
   Pod target -> Editor -> Add Build Phase -> Add Copy Bundle Build
   Phase
2. Manually add all XIB files used by JSQMessages to the created phase, with the + button.
3. Delete everything in the derived folder
4. Restart my Mac. Yeah, really, no Magical thinking here. XCode is full of misteries you humans can not decode.